# Second Normal Form of a Database In regards to Date

Tags: database, sqlite, relational-database, normalization

Having performed normalization on a database designed to record user information relating to there physical workout activities, I have come to realise that even though I could store information such as the Date in its own table, utilising a unique ID to identify each date, with the unique ID being used in the junction tables, I will still have repeated data and an extra storage requirement placing more strain upon the system.

My question is this, even though Date, Weight etc  will repeat potentially many times, regardless of how I store it, will it still count as 2NF due to being reliant upon the Primary Key, as to my understanding if repeat data was never allowed then no database would reach 2NF never mind 3rd.

Thanks

JHB92

Comment: Why do you think that duplicate date values violate the [definition of 2NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms)?

Comment: Its how it was explained to me however after reading your definition I can see that it doesnt!